# configure spark with delta undefined function in Python

Tags: python, apache-spark, pyspark, apache-spark-sql, delta-lake

recently I wanted to use delta lake according to its documentation like this:

https://docs.delta.io/latest/quick-start.html#set-up-apache-spark-with-delta-lake&language-python

I installed deltalake and built it, after that I installed pyspark + spark 3.2.1 (which obviously match the delta-1.1.0 version).
but when tried in my IntelliJ their example like bellow in the screen:

[image]

My Intellij don't find the proposed function to use "configure_spark_with_delta_pip"

I don't understand which isn't defined by the example's import of pyspark.

Do you have and idea of the problem and how I can solve it plz ?
BTY anyone have a real good first tutorial which work correclty ? (I precise, I'm beginner with spark and python because I never try/use before)

Thank a lot and best regarde

[image]

the link to delta import referral to

Comment: Have you installed the `delta-spark` Python package?

Comment: @AlexOtt of course (already installed before trying), I will add the attached installation' screen

Comment: works just fine for me. If you click on the `delta` package, and click `GoTo` - where do you go? Maybe there is another, conflicting package with name `delta` ?

Comment: @AlexOtt I added the picture, but I think isn't correctly, right (the venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/delta/__init__.py ? How I can change et what the good version to use ?